# Statement which will breakpoint PHP when debugging, and do nothing otherwise

Tags: php, debugging, breakpoints

When coding in C or C++ on an Intel processor, I can code this

```
__asm__("int $3");
```

If my code is executing in a debugger then it acts as breakpoint when encountered. If not, it has no effect.

I put it in major error spots in my code, so that execution will always stop there, even if I clear all breakpoints, and I won't need to reset those breakpoints.

That allows me to reserve "normal breakpoints" for whatever functionality I am currently testing, while knowing that I will also catch any undefined behaviour which I have marked thus,

Question: can I do something similar in PHP?

Comment: maybe http://php.net/manual/en/function.apd-breakpoint.php

Comment: It looks like a breakpoint keyword is coming soon: see https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0553/